# FTP server on VPS

Tags: ftp, vps

I am trying to connect to FileZilla ftp server on my VPS. I have installed it. Added a user. Added exception to Windows Firewall for FileZillaServer.exe; Configured FileZilla to use Passive mode and entered my IP of VPS server. Then I have started the server on VPS.
But I still can not connect to FileZilla from outside. It sais:
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server

P.S. if I`m connecting to server locally, ir works.

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I will answer it myself :)
I could not start Filezilla server for some reason, but I was able to start IIS FTP server. 
All you need to do is to go to IIS Manager and add FTP site. Add user and that`s it.